# Rails - four tables associations -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-models

a rails newbie here, looking at doing some work with 4 tables and not totally sure how to structure the associations.  Below topic involves real estate, probably helpful to keep that in mind.

I have four models:

- Property - a physical house
- Project - a large group of jobs happening at a house
- Job - a specific job at a house
- Worker - a person doing the work

The associations as I see them in my head are:

- a Property can have many Projects, Jobs, and Workers
- a single Project belongs to one Property, but can have many Jobs and (via Jobs) have many Workers
- a single Job belongs to one Project and to one Property (via the Project), but can have many Workers
- a single Worker can have one Job on one Projects on one Property

My two questions are:

1. What is the best way to think about the above set of relationships?
2. ** How do I build the associations between my models? Can't get my head wrapped around how to do that.

Really appreciate any thoughts!

***** UPDATED MODEL STRUCTURE - 9/30/2015
Thanks Jason - here is what I have now (below)

My key goal in working with the data will be the following:
- list a property, it's projects, jobs and workers
- list a set of projects and properties for a worker

Does the below model structure accomplish the above? It seems to from my view but can't totally be sure.

Model setup as 9/30

- Property Model
  has_many :projects
  has_many :jobs, through: :projects
  has_many :workers, through: :jobs
- Project Model
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :workers, through: :jobs
- Job Model
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :workers
- Worker Model
  has_many :jobs

Comment: Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. There you will learn about different types of associations, when to use which and how to set them up.

Comment: Thanks Egon, yeah I've seen that before.  It all "makes sense" when I read it but then when I try to do it for some reason it all turns into a mess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, I think you have this: A property can have many projects. Each project belongs to one property and can have many jobs. Each job belongs to one project and can have many workers. Each worker belongs to one job.

`Property` model:

```
has_many :projects
```

`Project` model:

```
belongs_to :property
has_many :jobs
```

`Job` model:

```
belongs_to :project
has_many :workers
```

`Worker` model:

```
belongs_to :job
```

Each `project` should have a `property_id`, each `job` should have a `project_id` and each worker should have a `job_id`. These can be established in your migration (with the `belongs_to` function) where you create the tables for these models. They'll look like this:

```
create_table :projects do |t|
  t.belongs_to :property, index: true
  .
  . # your other attribute(s) here
  .
end
```

That will give the `Project` model a `property_id` attribute, allowing you to access a `Project`'s `Property`.

Edit:

If you want to easily access all of a property's workers and all of a project's workers, you can add a `has_many` `through` association to each of the `Property` and `Project` models. Also, you can add another association to the `Property` model that will allow you to access all of a property's jobs. They will look like this:

`Property` model additions:

```
has_many :jobs, through: :projects
has_many :workers, through: :projects
```

`Project` model additions:

```
has_many :workers, through: :jobs
```

Edit: (OP clarified desired model scheme)

Now if we want to have it so a worker can be assigned to more than one property, a different type of association will be needed. First of all, this association will only need to handle the relationship between jobs and workers. Since every job has only one parent project, and every project has only one parent property, the project and property associated with any job that a worker has will be accessible through that job.

There are two options for this job to worker relationship: `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many` `through`. The key difference between these options is that each record in the `has_and_belongs_to_many` join table will only establish the association between a job and a worker and would not require a model, but the `has_many` `through` join table can contain additional information about that association. That additional information would be accessed through a separate model. This second option could, for example, be useful for keeping track of the number of hours that a worker logged on each job. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) is a more thorough description of the difference between these options.

If you have already created the `Worker` and `Job` models, you should generate a new migration to create this join table. Otherwise, you can include the following `create_table` in the migration file for the `Worker` or `Job` models.

Here is the migration code for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
def change
  create_table :jobs_workers do |t|
    t.belongs_to :job, index: true
    t.belongs_to :worker, index: true
  end
end
```

In the `Job` model, get rid of this:

```
has_many :workers
```

and replace it with this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :workers
```

In the `Worker` model, get rid of this:

```
belongs_to :job
```

and replace it with this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
```

An explanation of the `has_many` `through` association would be more lengthy, so I'll defer to [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Hi Jason,  really really appreciate your thoughts here.  Comment / questions...
1) in my case a worker will only belong to 1 job
2) in your above "property model addition"...is it:

has_many :jobs, through: :projects
has_many :workers, through: :projects

- or -

has_many :jobs, through: :projects
has_many :workers, through: :jobs

Note the 2nd line of "through: :projects" vs. "through: :jobs"

likewise, can I still find a list of properties via 1 worker this way?

Comment: Either of those will allow you to access all of the workers that are associated with a property. I'm confused about the last part of your comment, though, where you ask if you can "find a list of properties via 1 worker." I thought a worker, through their job and then their job's project, could only be associated with one property. Is that not accurate?

Comment: Well this is where perhaps I am thinking incorrectly.  For example, a worker could work on multiple properties, i.e. 10 Happy Street on Monday and then 20 Silly Street on Friday...
worker in this case is best thought of as an electrician / plumber, etc. so someone that could easily work on either one property a few times, or across multiple properties; however, at any point in time they are only working on 1 job at 1 property.  So you could imagine that you would want to find "what are all the properties that Bob has worked at?"

make sense?

Comment: See my above edit and keep the questions coming whenever they come up!

Comment: Thanks Jason - I updated the question based on our discussion - see the original question and look / search for the "UPDATED MODEL" 

Think I somehow prefer the "through:" approach, seems more clear to me and I might add to models later...(thanks again!)

Comment: Hi Jason, did that updated model association look right? Thanks!

Comment: Your associations between `:workers` and `:jobs` don't include the model that you need to be able to assign many workers to a job and vice versa. You said you were going to go with a `has_many` `through` association. That association needs a model that parallels the configuration seen [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), where their `Physician` and `Patient` correspond to your `Job` and `Worker`. The model (and join table) you need to create for this association corresponds to their `Appointment`.